# serverMiddleware access Nuxt instance or context

Tags: nuxt.js, servermiddleware

im trying to access Nuxt runtime variables from a serverMiddleware

Example i have this **context.$db** which i added from this plugin

**nuxt.config.js**:

```
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/db_runtime.js', mode: 'server' }
    ]
```

**~/plugins/db_runtime.js**:

```
    db = 'test'
    
    export default ({ app }, inject) => {
        inject('db', db)
    }
```

Then i added a serverMiddleware:

```
    serverMiddleware: [
        { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' },
    ],
```

The serverMiddleware: **~/api/index.js**:

```
    export default function(res, req) {
    }
```

Is there anyway to access **context.$db** from there?
i.e

```
    export default function(res, req) {
        $config.db = null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For static data, what i usually did is using either [environment variables (.env)](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env) or [modules](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules) declared in nuxt.config.js to pass the data.

For dynamic data, since serverMiddleware is always invoked in the same lifecycle of your nuxt app, you can safely send the data as HTTP request using [asyncData()](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching) or [fetch()](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching) or [axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/)

Please refer to the following link/diagram for serverMiddle lifecycle:

[Understanding modules, serverMiddleware and plugins in Nuxt.js configuration](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/90d98d426b764f11073431e33034d78ca9c93c17/bd6d7/docs/2.x/plugins.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% versed in the [Nuxt lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle) (v2.x), but afaik you CANNOT access the Nuxt app context during the serverMiddleware lifecycle phase.  `serverMiddleware` is really `connect`-based (used internally by Express, btw) for processing `req`, `res` and `next` parameters, which represent the request, the response, and `next` which is `connect`s flow management parameter.

The basic conceptual reason is that the Nuxt app context supports both the server and client-side, and the default 'universal' mode is a core objective of Nuxt.  `connect` is really a server-side only library designed to handle the request and response nature of an application server.

Since you need `config.$db`, provided the configuration values you need are static, there may be an alternative way to use the nuxt.config `env` and the general environment variables in `serverMiddleware`. `$config` is a newer Nuxt construct intended to allow more flexible runtime environment variables (as well as normal env vars).

Here is the [current 2.x link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#servermiddleware-vs-middleware) to the `middleware` vs `serverMiddleware` explanation provided by Nuxt. I've also cut/paste the text info in case the link on Nuxt decays.

> **serverMiddleware vs middleware!**
>
> Don't confuse it with routes `middleware` which are called before each route by Vue in Client Side or SSR. Middleware listed in the `serverMiddleware` property runs server-side before vue-server-renderer and can be used for server specific tasks like handling API requests or serving assets.

> Do not add `serverMiddleware` to the middleware/ directory.

> Middleware, are bundled by webpack into your production bundle and run on beforeRouteEnter. If you add `serverMiddleware` to the middleware/ directory it will be wrongly picked up by Nuxt as `middleware` and will add wrong dependencies to your bundle or generate errors.

Btw, as always, if I'm incorrect on any of the above, I'm always appreciative of Stackflow users who point out what is wrong or can be explained better